# How do you reset the count used for node labels in yEd?

Tags: label

I just finished creating a new diagram.  Now I want to put some numbered nodes in it so I can explain the process depicted in my diagram.  I have default labeling enabled.  When I click on the diagram, it creates a new node just fine, but it has a large number.  I want to reset the "count" so it starts creating nodes labeled 1, 2, 3, etc.

I'm using yEd 3.9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Help on the Preferences dialog reads:

> Create Default Label for New Nodes: If set, a consecutive numbering is used for the label of newly created nodes. Otherwise, the label of newly created nodes remains empty.

In my (one day of) experience, the auto-numbering is gapless, so yEd always uses the number of nodes you have + 1 for the new node's label. It seems there's no way to 'reset the count,' but you could:

- Put (optionally unlabeled) nodes in your diagram and manually renumber them
- Put nodes in the diagram and alter the generated XML

The XML seems very sane from a quick glance, so if you need to modify a large number of nodes, I'd look into that.